# Skype crashes after push save as

Tags: skype

Skype in my Ubuntu 18.04 crashes after I push a button "Save as" and no error message is displayed. What could be the reason?

Thanks

Comment: It's obviously a bug in Skype, you should be reporting it through `Help →  Report a problem…`, also possibly [through their forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1). You won't really get an answer here, because it's a closed source app, and Microsoft's staff is unlikely to appear here. FTR, the new Skype is known to be pretty unstable *(probably because they decided to rewrite everything from scratch, for whatever reason)*.

Comment: Thank for the recommendation and it is sad that Microsoft doesn't appear here.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_messms-skype_instamessms/skype-in-ubuntu-1804-crashes-after-i-push-a-button/0e76e554-05ff-4012-bd76-8bb8c011ea92?tm=1532603186710    it is link to request about a bug on their forum. I 'll wait for an answer.